# What would cause a CMD window to open after windows starts?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, boot

As of the past few weeks, when I start windows, A CMD window opens and stays open after all the programs and applications launch. I have just been exiting or closing the box, but I have been wondering what would cause it to open in the first place?

I have checked to see what is in start up (and I have been looking for CMD or RUN) but I don't see anything out of the ordinary.

How can I get this to stop?

I have windows 7 Home premium 64.

Comment: When a command prompt (cmd) seems to hang open, it's likely because a batch file is running that started a program and the program has not exited yet.  The suggestions to see what's starting are good, but this is likely why it's happening... something is starting another program through a batch file and the program is never closing (this COULD be normal behavior depending on what the program does). If this turns out to be something you WANTED running (that starts from the batch file), modify the batch file so that the program uses "START program.exe" (where program.exe is the program running).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it started suddenly first question would be did you install new software around that time or have thunderstorms etc.

If no new software was installed my first suspicion would be virus. scan with a good av program as well as spybot and malware bytes. If all 3 dont find any thing beyond cookies run scandisk to check the hdd for corruption. Check the system event logs for disk events after that.  If more then a few warnings are found, or if errors are found for disk0 then its likely a bad hdd.  after that all thats left is the startup items as mentioned by others.

I always start with worst case as its not unusual to catch a dying disk by chance that way ;)  If new software was recently installed try uninstalling it and or use a restore point. some hard to fix viruses and odd things like this are repairable that way.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) instead of `msconfig`. It has a far more complete list of startup locations. Click `Options > Hide Microsoft Entries`, then check the remaining entries for `CMD.EXE` or scripts from which the command prompt may have been launched.

Comment: How does the user check the remaining entries for CMD.EXE or scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how it starts, but I'll start with the easy way...

Go to **Start**, type `msconfig` and press Enter. Select the `Startup` tab, and click <kbd>Disable All</kbd>. Click on `Services`, and tick the box for `Hide Microsoft Services`, then click <kbd>Disable All</kbd>. Click OK, then reboot. Does the box go away?

If yes, then go back into `msconfig`, and go back to the Startup tab. Enable half the times, hit <kbd>OK</kbd> and restart. Does the box stay away? If yes, repeat this step. If it comes back, then **disable** half the items you enabled, and reboot

If not, then it is starting up somewhere else, such as a service or a driver or a virus.